How to make the '+' blinking of color red ,blue and green
TITLE clights.asm
DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 0100H

.DATA
.CODE

MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX

; --- Clear the screen ---
MOV AX, 0600H
MOV BH, 07H
MOV CX, 0000H
MOV DX, 184FH
INT 10H

; --- Display in the TOP LEFT corner (0,0) ---
MOV AH, 02H          ; Set cursor position
MOV BH, 00H          ; Display page 0
MOV DH, 00H          ; Row 0 (Top)
MOV DL, 00H          ; Column 0 (Left)
INT 10H

; --- First line ---
MOV CX, 80           ; Set the loop counter for 80 dots
MOV DL, '.'          ; Load the dot character
PRINT_FIRST_LINE:
MOV AH, 02H          ; DOS function to display a single character
INT 21H              ; Print the dot
LOOP PRINT_FIRST_LINE ; Decrement CX and loop if CX > 0

; --- Second line ---
MOV DL, '.'          ; Load the dot character
MOV CX, 68           ; Loop counter for 60 dots (after this we print plus signs)
PRINT_SECOND_LINE_DOTS:
MOV AH, 02H          ; DOS function to display a single character
INT 21H              ; Print the dot
LOOP PRINT_SECOND_LINE_DOTS ; Decrement CX and loop if CX > 0

; --- 1st line of 4th bulb ---
MOV DL, '+'          ; Load the plus character
MOV CX, 5            ; Loop counter for 5 plus signs
PRINT_SECOND_LINE_PLUS:
MOV AH, 02H          ; DOS function to display a single character
INT 21H              ; Print the plus sign
LOOP PRINT_SECOND_LINE_PLUS ; Decrement CX and loop if CX > 0

; --- End ---
MOV DL, '.'          ; Load the dot character again
MOV CX, 7            ; Loop counter for 7 dots (finish the line)
MOV AH, 02H          ; DOS function to display a single character
PRINT_SECOND_LINE_REST:
INT 21H              ; Print the dot
LOOP PRINT_SECOND_LINE_REST ; Decrement CX and loop if CX > 0

; --- Third line ---
MOV DL, '.'          ; Load the dot character
MOV CX, 66           ; Loop counter for 60 dots
PRINT_THIRD_LINE_DOTS:
MOV AH, 02H          ; DOS function to display a single character
INT 21H              ; Print the dot
LOOP PRINT_THIRD_LINE_DOTS ; Decrement CX and loop if CX > 0

MOV DL, '+'          ; Load the plus character
MOV CX, 2            ; Loop counter for 2 plus signs
PRINT_THIRD_LINE_PLUS:
MOV AH, 02H          ; DOS function to display a single character
INT 21H              ; Print the plus sign
LOOP PRINT_THIRD_LINE_PLUS ; Decrement CX and loop if CX > 0

MOV DL, '.'          ; Load the dot character again
MOV CX, 5            ; Loop counter for 5 dots (after the first plus signs)
PRINT_THIRD_LINE_DOTS_2:
MOV AH, 02H          ; DOS function to display a single character
INT 21H              ; Print the dot
LOOP PRINT_THIRD_LINE_DOTS_2 ; Decrement CX and loop if CX > 0

MOV DL, '+'          ; Load the plus character again
MOV CX, 1            ; Loop counter for 1 plus sign
PRINT_THIRD_LINE_PLUS_2:
MOV AH, 02H          ; DOS function to display a single character
INT 21H              ; Print the plus sign
LOOP PRINT_THIRD_LINE_PLUS_2 ; Decrement CX and loop if CX > 0

MOV DL, '.'          ; Load the dot character again
MOV CX, 6            ; Loop counter for 6 dots (finish the line)
PRINT_THIRD_LINE_REST:
MOV AH, 02H          ; DOS function to display a single character
INT 21H              ; Print the dot
LOOP PRINT_THIRD_LINE_REST ; Decrement CX and loop if CX > 0

; --- Exit program ---
MOV AX, 4C00H         ; Terminate program
INT 21H

END

In this line code ; --- 1st line of 4th bulb ---
MOV DL, '+'          ; Load the plus character
MOV CX, 5            ; Loop counter for 5 plus signs
PRINT_SECOND_LINE_PLUS:
MOV AH, 02H          ; DOS function to display a single character
INT 21H              ; Print the plus sign
LOOP PRINT_SECOND_LINE_PLUS ; Decrement CX and loop if CX > 0

I want it to be blinking colors

You can use INT 10h function 09h to write a character and an attribute, but none of them blink.  To get blinking, you have to write the characters again in a new color.

The DOS output functions like the one that you're using (AH=02h) don't care about colors at all. You need to use the BIOS output functions if color is what you want. You could also write directly to the video memory, but let's keep it simple for now.
For a displayed character to start blinking, you must set bit 7 of its attribute byte. You already cleared the screen using the attribute 07h, so by setting 87h all of the screen characters would begin blinking. Of course that's not what you want in this case, so you'll need to be selective.
I wrote next demo and tested it in DOSBox so you can see this in action:
  ORG  256

  mov  ax, 072Eh   ; WhiteOnBlack '.'
  mov  cx, 80+68
  mov  dx, 0000h   ; At(0,0);
  call TypeChars

  mov  ax, 842Bh   ; Blinking RedOnBlack '+'
  mov  cx, 5
  mov  dx, 0144h   ; At(68,1);
  call TypeChars

  mov  ax, 072Eh   ; WhiteOnBlack '.'
  mov  cx, 7+66
  mov  dx, 0149h   ; At(73,1);
  call TypeChars

  mov  ax, 812Bh   ; Blinking BlueOnBlack '+'
  mov  cx, 2
  mov  dx, 0242h   ; At(66,2);
  call TypeChars

  mov  ax, 072Eh   ; WhiteOnBlack '.'
  mov  cx, 5
  mov  dx, 0244h   ; At(68,2);
  call TypeChars

  mov  ax, 822Bh   ; Blinking GreenOnBlack '+'
  mov  cx, 1
  mov  dx, 0249h   ; At(73,1);
  call TypeChars

  mov  ax, 072Eh   ; WhiteOnBlack '.'
  mov  cx, 6
  mov  dx, 024Ah   ; At(74,1);
  call TypeChars

  mov  ah, 00h     ; BIOS.WaitKeystroke
  int  16h         ; -> AX

  mov  ax, 4C00h   ; DOS.TerminateProgram
  int  21H
; ----------------
; IN (ax,cx,dx) OUT () MOD (ax)
TypeChars:
  push bx
  mov  bl, ah      ; Attribute
  mov  bh, 0       ; Display page 0
  mov  ah, 02h     ; BIOS.SetCursorPosition
  int  10h
  mov  ah, 09h     ; BIOS.WriteCharAndAttribute
  int  10h
  pop  bx
  ret

